# Have the 613 commandments ever been ranked by order of importance?

Tags: mitzvah, aseres-hadibros

Has any major commentator ever attempted to rank the 613 commandments by order of importance?  There are hints in the Sources about relative importance: The Ten Commandments, the Noahide Laws, the Big Three of pikuach nefesh, Hillel's Golden Rule, the chukkim, tzedakah [Bava Batra 9a, Ketubot 68a], and many others.

Yet the Mishna tells us not to do it: Be as scrupulous in observing a minor commandment as a major commandment, because you do not know the value of each commandment. [Avot 2:1]

Nevertheless, has anybody attempted a ranking?

Comment: I think you need to better define "importance" of this question. It's too vague a term, here. I think the Mishnah that you cited has perhaps been reason alone not to rank any of them. However, we know that there are clearly some that are more "important" than others and the criteria is probably based on the punishment for its violation. E.g. - observing Shabbat is prob. more "important" than giving tzedaka.based on that criterion.

Comment: I ask if this was ever attempted under ANY definition of "importance".

Comment: I think "reward" is probably a more accurate translation of "מַתַּן שְׂכָרָן" than "value" - which is to say, one could still rank "importance" based on other frameworks, such as which trumps which in a conflict; severity of punishment; requirements for atonement... (Re the last one, see e.g. Maimonides Laws of Repentance where he presents a *general* classification based.)

Comment: The prophets did something like this.  
(1) תלמוד בבלי מסכת מכות דף כד/א 
בא מיכה והעמידן על שלש דכתיב הגיד לך אדם מה טוב ומה ה' דורש ממך כי אם עשות משפט ואהבת חסד והצנע לכת עם (ה') אלהיך וכו' בא חבקוק והעמידן על אחת שנאמר וצדיק באמונתו יח. Accordingly, the most "important" mitzvah is emunah. This is easy to understand, because without emunah, there are no mitzvos.

Comment: @shmu Interestingly, this didn't make its way to Geonim and Rambam. That's why I didn't include it in my answer. It seems that they didn't have the 613 clear cut Mitzvos as we do, they just followed the prophets.

Comment: @shmu I don't think you would say that Emuna is more important than murdering people or worshipping idols ?

Comment: @AlBerko I would say that the basic principles of emunah (existence of G-d, revelation of Torah, reward and punishment -- see Sefer Ikarim) are the sine qua non of all mitzvos, including the 3 cardinal sins. If a person doesn't believe in Torah, he won't keep it.

Comment: @shmu do we hang or stone one who does not believe? Judaism is practical - Just do it! (no association...) nobody tests your beliefs as long as you behave.

Comment: Maybe the Mishna you quote in Avos proves we can't rank the Mitzvos...

Comment: @AlBerko the Rambam rules that a Jew can lose his olam haba due to improper beliefs (apikorsus), and this is even worse than being hung and stoned (see Shaarei Teshuvah by Rabbeinu Yonah). However, the Nesivos Shalom (Slonim) writes that we cannot measure the importance of a mitzvah by the punishment incurred by its violation.

Answer (score -2):

While there's no accepted hierarchy of all the Mitzvos, here are Some ways of classifying Mitzvos by "importance":

**1. By the severity of punishment:**

- Missing a Positive Mitzvah (not sitting in Succah)
- Doing Teshuva (e.g. Ona'ah less than 1/6)
- Paying back + Teshuva (e.g. Gezel)
- Lashes/corporal punishment (eating pork)
- 4 types of capital punishment (Arayos or Shabbos)
- Kares (eating on Yom Kippur)

**2. By Rabbinical preferences** examples:

- "Talmud Torah against them all..."
- 3 Mitzvos of "To die and not transgress" - murder, idolatry, adultery
- Pikuach Nefesh (not actually a Mitzvah) overrides all others
- Wasting seed / Marrying a Shiktze
- [Not] Performing circumcision (Bris with G-d)
- the 10 commandments, esp. the first 5

etc.

Comment: -"Nevertheless, has anybody attempted a ranking?"
This doesn't answer the question. -1

Comment: @רבותמחשבות This was my first sentence - there's no accepted system of ranking. I brought the existing attempts. take your -1 back.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Well, Al did mention "Talmud Torah against them all...", which is a Mishnah in Pe'ah, I believe. So someone did at least rank Talmud Torah as the highest or more important than th erest of the group mentioned there. And the rest of the list does have an "importance". I have to think about the rest of the answer, myself. But I think Al does at least answer the question.

Comment: @DanF that's not an attempted ranking of the 613 mitzvos - that's an aggadah emphasizing the importance of a single mitzvah!  The OP already did that in the question!

Comment: @DanF -- The Talmud also says: Idolatry is so serious a sin that its rejection fulfills the whole Torah. [Nedarim 25a]

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Well, OK. I don't think anyone has ranked each of the 613 individually and assigned an importance "number" to each one. But, I do think that several places have "categorized" a few groups in terms of  "importance".

Comment: @DanF Well, that was the question: "Has any major commentator ever attempted to rank the 613 commandments by order of importance?" The answer is no, unless you find one of the monei hamitzvos who explained that that is their rationale in counting them.